# Possible to get cities near me with Foursquare?

Tags: foursquare

is it possible to find all the cities near me if I send to the foursquare api a longitude and latitude?

I been looking at their api and not seeing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't something that the Foursquare API supports.

Comment: Thanks. I actually figured that this is not the best way to go about and that what foursquare does do is actually better :) Probably would be still a good feature in the future though.